# JOGL + Swing does not initialize properly

Tags: java, swing, jogl

I am trying to get JOGL working correctly with Swing. I have used WindowBuilder and hacked it together with a few JOGL examples. It works fine, but there is a problem. When I start the program, it starts with blank window. Even the Swing components do not come up:

[image]

Everything starts to work when I move mouse cursor over the window content or another event forces it to redraw - like change of focus, window move, re-size etc.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.media.opengl.GL;
import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;

public class OpenGLTestMin {
    private JFrame frame;
    private Animator animator;
    private double theta = 0;
    private double s = 0;
    private double c = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    OpenGLTestMin window = new OpenGLTestMin();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public OpenGLTestMin() {
        frame = new JFrame();

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowevent) {
                animator.stop();
                frame.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        // frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();
        panelMain.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panelMain = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panelMain.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panelMain.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panelMain.gridy = 0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(panelMain, gbc_panelMain);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panelMain = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panelMain.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panelMain.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panelMain.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panelMain.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panelMain.setLayout(gbl_panelMain);

        JPanel panelButton = new JPanel();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_panelButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panelButton.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panelButton.gridx = 1;
        gbc_panelButton.gridy = 0;
        panelMain.add(panelButton, gbc_panelButton);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panelButton = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panelButton.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panelButton.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
        gbl_panelButton.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panelButton.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panelButton.setLayout(gbl_panelButton);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btn1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btn1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
        gbc_btn1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_btn1.gridy = 0;
        panelButton.add(btn1, gbc_btn1);

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_btn2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btn2.gridx = 0;
        gbc_btn2.gridy = 1;
        panelButton.add(btn2, gbc_btn2);


        GLProfile glprofile = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities glcapabilities = new GLCapabilities(glprofile);
        GLJPanel glcanvas = new GLJPanel(glcapabilities);

        glcanvas.addGLEventListener(new GLEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void init(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable) {
            }

            @Override
            public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable) {
            }

            @Override
            public void display(GLAutoDrawable glautodrawable) {
                theta += 0.01;
                s = Math.sin(theta);
                c = Math.cos(theta);

                GL2 gl = glautodrawable.getGL().getGL2();
                gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
                gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                gl.glVertex2d(-c, -c);
                gl.glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
                gl.glVertex2d(0, c);
                gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
                gl.glVertex2d(s, -s);
                gl.glEnd();
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_panel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_panel.gridx = 0;
        gbc_panel.gridy = 0;
        panelMain.add(glcanvas, gbc_panel);

        animator = new Animator(glcanvas);
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. `GLJPanel` should be initialized directly in `main` method, not in `EventQueue`. Then it works just fine. Also note that `GLCanvas` has MUCH better performance than `GLJPanel`, however sometimes glitches a bit when resizing window.